# Migrating to 10.4, functions Eip and Ebp called on pointer context are unknown

Tags: pointers, delphi, migration, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm trying to migrate some code from the previous RAD version to the 10.4.

Hovewer, I've stumbled on this piece of code:

```
function GetCallStack(Context: PContext): TList; overload;
begin
  Result := GetCallStack(Pointer(Context^.Eip), Pointer(Context^.Ebp));
end;
```

It's a part of the exception handling and logging and I believe it was copied from somewhere. It worked previously, but now I'm getting this error:

```
E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Eip' at line 104
E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Ebp' at line 104
```

I never dived to deep into pointers, so can anybody explain me how to fix this code?

I can provide the whole unit if it is required.

Comment: I would also appreciate some tips for a better header for this topic.

Comment: If you are using a third party exception logging library that has support for getting call stacks then update it to a newer version. Also what are you updating from?

Comment: No 3rd party, it is a custom exception hook module.
I believe the project was first made for either XE5 or Delphi 2009. It wasn't modified for a long time, since about 2017.

Comment: `Eip` and `Ebp` are not supposed to be functions but fields of [this structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-wow64_context).

Comment: @Olivier So how can I fix this part of a code?

Comment: Are you compiling in 32 bits?

Comment: Answer can be found in the code which we can't see

Comment: The contents of the `Context` structure depend on the build type.  For instance, if you are compiling for 64bit, then `EIP` is extended into `RIP`, and `EBP` is extended into `RBP`. See [`CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-context) and [`WOW64_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-wow64_context) on MSDN.

Comment: @Olivier No, it's 64. I see now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks! I'll check it. Seems like what's I need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What should I provide? I can upload a whole unit.

Comment: Updating custom exception handling code that unwinds the stack from 32 to 64 bits might involve a lot of deep diving into pointers.

Comment: @Brian Yeah... Maybe I'm better searching for some 3rd party libs or units. You know something that's free? I'm not seeing my boss spending 300+$ on something like EurekaLog.

Comment: I should probably clarify what I'm looking for. I got a very elusive, but critical bug in a program. I want something that could save or show call stack on error, so I could find it. I've hoped to salvage this code from the old project, but it didn't turned out well.

Comment: How much did you “cost“ your boss already for searching this bug with improper tooling? Compare this value against a license of e.g. EurekaLog or madExcept... and then ask him again!

Comment: Jedi Code Library (JCL) is a free 3rd party library to catch the stack trace when an exception arises.

Comment: Another option: stay in 32 bits. Why do you need 64 bits?

Comment: @Olivier Our 3rd party libs are 64 bits only. And I'm a technician, not a full-time programmer, to code a wrapper.